# Differences between Gitkraken staging to "git add"

Tags: git, git-gui

I am having an issue with git CLI

background:
I am running code `prettier` on my staged files on pre-commit git hook.
but it works to format my code only if the user uses Gitkraken.

after investigation, I saw that git has different behavior from Gitkraken.

when I use Gitkraken to stage changes, I can see the diff
[image]

but if I use `git add .` to stage files, there is no change to the files.

[image]

and I think this is the cause of the problem that prettier does not see any files to work with when using git CLI.

Comment: A pre-commit hook is not called when adding files to the index.

Comment: I know, only before commit action.